# Telerik Access a Radgrid which is inside a RadListView

Tags: vb.net, telerik, radgrid, radlistview

I have a radgrid which is nested inside a radlistview. Does anybody know how to reference the radgrid from a button click? I am currently looping through the radlistview and i would like to loop through the radgrid within that loop.

```
For Each item As RadListViewDataItem In RadListView1.Items

 'I AM SAVING RADLISTVIEW ITEMS HERE

            'THIS IS THE POINT WHERE I NEED TO ACCESS RADGRID1 
            'WHICH I DON'T KNOW HOW TO DO

            For Each item As GridDataItem In Radgrid1.MasterTableView.Items

             'I WILL BE SAVING RADGRID ITEMS HERE

            Next

Next
```

Answer (score 0):

After messing about for ages, I found out how to do what I wanted about two minutes after posting the question. Basically I'm using FindControl to get my radgrid which I can then loop through as normal. Not sure why I didn't think of that earlier.

```
Dim gvHours As RadGrid = DirectCast(item.FindControl("gvHours"), RadGrid)

For Each item As GridDataItem In gvHours.MasterTableView.Items

    'DO STUFF HERE

Next
```